# Form Page in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Creating a Form Page in HTML. So far it looks good but i am trying to get it so that when the user inputs all of the information and clicks submit, it will then display the info he/she has entered in the fields below it.I have attached the image for clarification. I will also paste what I have done so far.

`HTML CODE`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">


        .button1 {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
}

    body{
        max-width:500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }   



    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1> Welcome to my Website</h1>

    <p> Sign Up</p>
    <form>

        First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
</br>
  Date of Birth:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Birth">
</br>
  Phone Number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Number">
</br>

 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other

    </form>

    <p> Interests</p>

    <input type="checkbox" name="school" value="Data Base" checked> DataBase<br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="school" value="Web Programming"> Web<br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="school" value="Software Engineering"> Software Engineering</br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="school" value="Machine Learning" checked> Machine Learning<br>

<button class = "button1" type = "button"> Sign Up</button> 


</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: What's the ask/error ?

Comment: How can I get the users info passed into the boxes  under the form screen. After they enter the info and click Sign Up it should show it in the empty fields.

Comment: You'll need JavaScript (or a server side language) to do this. What have *you* tried?

Comment: I am just learning html/css and haven't learned javascript yet(planning to). Is there any other way without js?

Comment: @jsilva You will need either `javascript` or a server side language. `HTML` is just a markup, it doesn't have a lot of brains.

Comment: okay thanks guys. Gonna go back to the drawing board then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your example, the page is static but your need is to make this page dynamic. For this reason, you have to develop this part with a programming language (JS, or server side language).

First option, you can retrieve form data passed in URL with this object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location and write the part of page you want with DOM API after the page was loaded.

Second Option, depending of the way you generate this page or not, you can generate the part of page with form data passed in URL.